# How to use a state and local keywords for a single variable in perl?

Tags: perl, scope

While reading about the state and local method in Perl, I had one doubt.

state: This is used to define the static variables for a subroutines.

local: This is used to define the local variable, but if the variable is defined using the local method, it is visible to the called subroutines also.

My question is:

Is it possible to define a single variable with both the state and local functionalities. If it is possible please give me an example.

I tried below but it gives error.

```
 local state $a;
 state local $b;
```

Comment: If this were possible, what would you use it for?

Comment: I don't know where I am going to use this. While reading I had this question. Is it possible or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare a variable with both state and local. You can use them in different scopes.

For example using global:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use common::sense;

our $global = 1;

change();
unchanged();

sub change {

    local $global = 3;

    print "> $global\n";

}

sub unchanged {

    print "> $global\n";

}
```

It will print 3 and 1 because our allows you change the value of your variable depending on your scope.

According to [perldoc - Persistent-Private-Variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Persistent-Private-Variables):

> Beginning with Perl 5.10.0, you can declare variables with the state
>   keyword in place of my.

And as some examples you can change it too:

> For example, the following code maintains a private counter,
>   incremented each time the gimme_another() function is called:

```
     use feature 'state';
    sub gimme_another { state $x; return ++$x }
```

And this example uses anonymous subroutines to create separate counters:

```
use feature 'state';
sub create_counter {
return sub { state $x; return ++$x }
}
```

> Also, since $x is lexical, it can't be reached or modified by any Perl
>   code outside.

Basically what you are trying to do is not possible, It is like if you were trying to declare:

```
local my $a
my local $b
```

Comment: Welcome to the Perl tag! Can you please fix the _perldod_ typo and add a link to the relevant doc? Besides that, very good answer. Keep them coming! :)

Comment: Thank you @simbabque, I already changed and added a link to the perldoc ! Hopefully I will answer more and more :)

Comment: Re "*You can't declare a variable with both state and local*", Mostly because there's no such thing as a "variable declared with local". `local` doesn't declare a variable; it makes a backup of an existing variable.

Answer (score 4):

In Perl, `local` does not declare variables (unlike e.g. `my` or `state`). Instead, `local` temporarily changes the value of an existing (global) variable. You can't use `local` with real local (i.e. lexically scoped) variables, such as the ones created by `my` or `state`.

Answer (score 2):

`state` (like `my`) creates a lexically-scoped variable. `local` creates temporary backups of package variables, hash elements and array elements. Since a `state` variable is none of those, `local` can't be used to backup a `state` variable.

If you want to make a temporary backup of a `state` variable, you could use something like [Sub::ScopeFinalizer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sub::ScopeFinalizer).

```
my $guard = scope_finalizer { $var = $_[0] } [ $var ];
```